# at least one group of all html elements filled jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say that I have some html like this:

```
<div class="users" id="user_1">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />

    Sex : <br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female

    Comments: 
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>

<br />

<div class="users" id="user_2">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />

    Sex : <br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female

    Comments: 
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>

<br />

<div class="users" id="user_3">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" />

    Sex : <br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female

    Comments: 
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see above I have three divs. All the fields in each div are required. I would like to know if the user has filled ALL the fields in at least ONE of the divs above using jquery. What is the easiest and most efficient way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Start looping through the outer elements.
Within the loop, loop through the input elements inspecting the value of each.
If you loop through all of the input elements inside an outer div, and didn't find a blank input, you've found a div full of non-empty inputs. Break out of the outer loop.

```
var allFormValid = false;

$('.users').each(function(i, form) {
 var formValid = true;
 $(form).children().each(function(j, input) {
  if($(input).val() === '') {
   formValid = false;
   return false;
  }
 });
 if(formValid) {
  allFormValid = true;
  return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Any explanation would be useful at leas to prevent marking your question as a low quality by an automatic process.